# RouterLink Does not Work Correctly

Tags: angular, angular4-router, routerlink

I have 2 components 1 for navigation and one for the contant of the page 
, RouterLink add the route path to the current routes 
for example if this routes

```
    {path:'home',component:HomeComponent},
    {path:'mygames/:id',component:UsergamesComponent}
```

And this the routerLink code

```
  <li class="treeview" routerLinkActive="active" >
      <a [routerLink]="['mygames',user_ob.user_id]">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>My Games</span>
      </a>
    </li>
```

When I navigate to home Route or any thing else and I want to Go to mygames route suppose the link will be localhost:4200/mygames/id but
The routerlink is

`localhost:4200/home/mygames/user_id`

or even on the home route The routerLink for this route is

```
localhost:4200/home/home
```

I do not Know what is the problem hear and how to fix it

Comment: Shouldn't the link be ['/mygames', user_ob.user_id] ?

Comment: this is correct

Comment: "/" is the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

routerLink can be use  as

```
 <a routerLink="/mygames/{{user_ob.user_id}}">
```

or

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/mygames',user_ob.user_id]">
```

more on [Angular DOC](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)